# element not getting printed in map

Tags: c++

I am getting an error while accessing elements in `map`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<utility>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int,string> > vec;

    vec.push_back(make_pair(2,"hello"));
    vec.push_back(make_pair(3,"world"));
    vec.push_back(make_pair(4,"fresh"));

    map<int,string>  map_word(vec.begin(),vec.end());


    cout<<map_word[0].second<<endl;  //ERROR
    return 0;
}
```

If I replace it with -> `(*(map_word.begin())).first` then the error gets resolved. In the line with `//ERROR` why `map_word` is behaving as an iterator whereas I haven't declared it as an iterator?

Comment: `map_word[0]` returns a value corresponding to key `0`. 1) The value is a `string`, so it doesn't have a field `second` (as the error says: `{aka class std::basic_string}’ has no member named ‘second’`). 2) `map_word` doesn't contain key `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map_word is a map of key-value.
The [] operator for map_word takes key as parameter and returns the value,

```
value_type& operator[] (const key_type& k);
value_type& operator[] (key_type&& k);
```

i.e. it can be used as

```
value_type value = map_word[key]
```

So when you do map_word[0], it returns the value for key 0, not the  pair.
You are mistaking [] and trying to use it as random access operator specifying the index.
i.e. the type for map_word[0] is *string* and not the *pair*